# Get data from UIWebView with stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, ios, webview

I want to catch an image from a `UIWebView`. 
So I run the following code on the WebView where the website is completely loaded.

```
    NSString *test = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByClassName('first-carousel-item')[0].getAttribute('data-img');"];
    NSLog(@"test %@", test);
```

But the log writes:

```
Printing description of test: <object returned empty description>
```

The Javascript works well on the Chrome console.

Answer (score 0):

if u want to catch anything from a webview don't forget to delegate it

```
[webView setDelegate:Self];
```

and when it uses the image use the webViewDidFinishLoad

if u any more questions i here :D